# How do you compile a java program from the command line while using selenium in the source code?

Tags: java, selenium, compiler-errors

I am working on a final project for my Computer Science course. I built an program using the Selenium library to automate the process of creating a github repo and linking it to a local folder. I am only able to run the program inside of VS Code using their "Run" feature. I want to be able to run this from the Command Line in Windows, but I am not able to compile it since Java doesn't recognize Selenium object types like WebDriver and WebElement. How would I compile it using this outside library?

Comment: Hi @Ayrock618, this question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only, which is the Selenium part, and provides more details on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strongly recommended to use Maven for java projects. It can fetch all the needed dependencies if you have added the maven dependency to the pom.xml file.

Otherwise download the Selenium jar file and use the following command to compile your code.

```
javac -cp .:jarfile1.jar:jarfile2.jar <MainClass>.java
```

and run the following to execute

java MainClass

Comment: Glad to help! it is very convenient to use Maven instead of adding dependencies manually.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial for adding these dependencies with Maven?

Comment: You could create maven project with an IDE (vscode, eclipse) or command line. After creating the project, there will be a pom.xml file in the root directory of the project. That is where all the dependencies must be added.

Here is a link on creating Maven project.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

The link also contains information on how to compile build the project using Maven.